# Is it possible to use jQuery to make a pandas table filterable/searchable?

Tags: python, jquery, html, pandas, flask

I am using Flask to build a web app but I am currently stuck trying to create a filterable table (built using pandas) with a search box where you can search for an item in a row and the table will collapse when the item is found. Like the one here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_filters.asp

In the above example the jQuery filter function is applied to a table created directly in the html template, but I am having a hard time getting this to work with a pandas dataframe (nothing happens when I try searching via the search box).

Any help would be appreciated :)

My run.py is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def table():
    df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
    return render_template("test.html", data=df.to_html(index=False))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my test html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $({{data}}).filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Browse Phosphosites</h2>
      <br><br>
      <p>Search the table for selected phosphosites or associated genes, chromosome locations and sequences:</p>  
      <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <br><br>
      {{data | safe }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working trial for one approach:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, session, request

import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)

template = """
<!doctype html>
<input type="text" value="" name="my_filter" id="my_filter">

<div id="results">{{ data|safe }}</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#my_filter').keyup(function() {
       if ($(this).val().length >= 1) {
           var requested_code = document.getElementById('my_filter').value;

           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               data: JSON.stringify({
                   'requested_code': requested_code
               }),
               contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
               url: "{{ url_for('filter_html') }}",
               success: function(resp) {
                   $("#results").html(resp);
               }
           });

       }
});
</script>
</html>
"""

@app.route("/")
def table():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
    session['df'] = df.values.tolist()
    return render_template_string(template, data=df.to_html(index=False))


@app.route('/filter', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def filter_html():
    df = pd.DataFrame(session['df'], columns=['a', 'b'])
    df = df[df['a'] == int(request.json.get('requested_code'))]
    return df.to_html(index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'hello'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Essentially, add a JQuery function to the `input` box that looks for `keyup` events. However, these should trigger an AJAX request to a URL endpoint in Flask that can then update the `"results"` div. There may be cleaner ways to serialize the data to be stored in a session; this is just to illustrate an approach.

The default `session` is rather small in Flask. If you try to store an object that's too large to fit, it won't error, the issue is just silently ignored. You will want to use `flask-session` to store the DF data; you're currently sending the whole thing to the browser so I assume it's not particularly large.

For anyone less familiar with Flask but working with Pandas: You can run this code and then navigate to `127.0.0.1:5000` in your browser. The numbers 1, 2 or 3 are valid to enter into the search box to interact with the df, anything else results in an empty df.